# is there any way to enter into fullscreen mode onload of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, fullscreen

I am working on quiz and want to convert the screen into **fullscreen mode on load of page** for specific time, is there any way to achieve this or any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

User interaction is required to enter full-screen mode. This is a security feature.

Imagine being able to force a popup window of some kind to go full screen, lock the mouse pointer, and play an ad without permission.
Having an "Enable Full Screen" **link or button** whose visibility is toggled in the "Change Full Screen" event handler in the
the documentation seems like a pragmatic/better approach.

Even if you'll try, you will get the following error message

> Failed to execute 'requestFullScreen' on 'Element': API can only be
> initiated by a user gesture.

So, It's not possible to load a page on fullscreen mode but you can use the following code to trigger it on some action:

```
<script>
/* Get the documentElement (<html>) to display the page in fullscreen */
var elem = document.documentElement;

/* View in fullscreen */
function openFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}

/* Close fullscreen */
function closeFullscreen() {
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    document.msExitFullscreen();
  }
}
</script>
```

Reference: [w3Schools - Full Screen](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen.asp)

Comment: Thanks @jjackofall for this,but I want to achieve this through onload event for specific page only. do you have any other ways to achive this(without user interaction)?